# Let $\alpha=\sqrt[5]{2}+\sqrt{5}$, show that $\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Tags: field-theory

> Let $\alpha=\sqrt[5]{2}+\sqrt{5}$, show that $\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Obviously $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ so $\sum q\alpha^i\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$.

But what next, how do I approach these type of problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
a=\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[5]{2}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad(a-\sqrt{5})^5=2
$$
Hence
$$
a^5-5a^4\sqrt{5}+50a^3-50a^2\sqrt{5}+250a-25\sqrt{5}=2
$$
and thus
$$
\sqrt{5}=\frac{a^5+50a^3+250a-2}{5a^4+50a^2+25}\in\mathbb Q[a].
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$\bigl(\alpha-\sqrt5\bigr)^5=2$.